# Python 2.7.5 Random Program Unknown Error

Tags: integer, division

In my programming class, we are doing an assignment where we need to calculate how often a certain result occurs at random.

The scenario is as follows...

people are in the line at a concert, and they are giving away 3 free tickets. The first person has a 50% chance to get a ticket. If he gets a ticket, the process repeats on person 2. A 50% chance to get a ticket, but there is one less ticket. 
 I need to have a program figure out how often the 6th person will get a ticket.

Here is what i have so far...

```
from __future__ import division
import random
trial =0
person =0
tickets_left =3
num6_w_ticket =0
for i in range (0,100):
    while tickets_left != 0:
        trial += 1
        win =random.randint(1,2)
        if win == 2:
            tickets_left -= 1
            person += 1
        if win != 2:
            person += 1
        if win ==2 and trial ==6:
            num6_w_ticket += 1
            tickets_left -= 1
avg = (num6_w_ticket * 100) / (trial * 100)
print "   >>>",avg,"% of the time, the 6th person got a ticket."
```

If anyone can spot the problem, that would be great!